# "Speak Cells on Enter," not showing in Excel Options -> Quick Access Toolbar -> All Commands

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, power-query, text-to-speech, qat

Where is, "Speak Cells on Enter?

Hopefully the attached screenshot says it all. "Speak Cells on Enter," is not showing up in Excel Options -> QAT -> All Commands. Anything I need to do?

[image: Where is, "Speak Cells on Enter?"]

Comment: For my machines and up to date Excel 365, Speak Cells and Stop Speaking are what is offered.  Is there an Excel Add-in you are thinking of?

Comment: John, thank you so much. I uninstalled and reinstalled 365 to ensure I have the latest version. Are you saying Speak Cells on Enter was removed?

Comment: There is no such thing on my Excel machines here (one machine is 2 moths old with new Excel, one is many year old with Excel a year or so old but up to date and one in the middle. I have not seen Speak Cells on Enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it via the search box. Type "Speak". Select it from the list in the Actions category.

[image: Speak Cells on Enter - Search]

Comment: What a delightful solution. Thank you, Reddy Lutonadio. If I had 15 reputation, I would certainly +1 your response! Have a delightful afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much to user Reddy Lutonadio. The feature was renamed to, "On Enter."

[image: Speak Cells on Enter renamed feature as On Enter in the QAT.]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).